# Removing QgsVectorLayer from QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector, remove

I managed to add `QgsVectorLayer` in `QGIS` through a Python plugin, for example:

```py
vl = self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layerName, self.dbConn.getProviderName())
```

But how can I remove it?

Comment: Didn't know that you could actually use this method in a variable assignment. Helped me solve a problem that I didn't know I had :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### For QGIS 3 versions and higher

One can remove a single `QgsVectorLayer` with:

```py
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer( vl.id() )
```

otherwise for many layers:

```py
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([ vl.id() ])
```

### For QGIS 2 versions and lower

One can remove a single `QgsVectorLayer` with:

```py
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer( vl.id() )
```

otherwise for many layers:

```py
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers([ vl.id() ])
```

Or if by chance you want to remove all empty layers, check out the [Remove empty layers from the map](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RemoveEmptyLayers/) plugin.

Comment: ok -- note that I just edited the answer to use your `vl` variable.