# Removing a vector layer from QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Considering my program is generating a shapefile that has to be added to the "Layers" tab in QGIS interface. However, once the utility of the layer is completed, I need to remove the layer in the middle of the code. I want to remove only the active layer and not all.

To put it in easier words, is there an opposite to `self.iface.addVectorLayer()` ?

Comment: Thanks @Akhil but your question may be seen as a duplicate if the solution in the referenced post worked for you. I will post it and let the moderators decide.

Comment: Absolutely. Do the needful, please. This could however assist others when they use a different set of search keywords, but it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question may be seen as a duplicate with this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42363/how-to-remove-a-vector-qgsvectorlayer-from-qgis-python-plugin), in which case I will happily remove my answer.

The solution, provided by @andytilia, involves using the following command for versions of QGIS from 1.8 to 2.99.

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers( [vl.id()] )
```

The solution involves using the following command for QGIS 3.X.

```
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( [vl.id()] )
```

Comment: It's actually the opposite. From [the docs](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html#a55af387e97ddf930fd13e1a53fd484ac): "This method is deprecated since QGIS 1.8, you should use removeMapLayers rather."

Comment: This command works if you have add the layer. But I have a problem with vector layer defined and not loaded in the project which not allow the deletion of the temporary folder of my QGIS plugin