# Closing QgsRasterLayer's file handler in Python script

Tags: raster, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

I'm creating a `QgsRasterLayer` from temporary file, as result from some processing algorithm.

After that, I no longer can delete file, as expected. But, because It is only a temp file, I need delete It after all my processing is done.

I tried, without success:

```py
layer = QgsRasterLayer("myTempFile.tif")

#Do some work...

del layer
```

`myTempFile.tif` still can't be deleted, but only after closing QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar thread which you can also read: [Removing a vector layer from QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130756/removing-a-vector-layer-from-qgis)

Try something like this, you will need to adapt it to reflect the layer(s) you are working with.

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer('path/to/your/raster.tif')

#do the rest of your code

QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
```