# Removing layers with zero features from QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8

I have more than 100 layers loaded in map canvas. Some layers don't have any feature. I would like to delete all layer with zero feature count.

Is it possible to get a script which can delete all these layers?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better than a script, there's a plugin to achieve it, and it's called "Remove empty layers from the map."

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RemoveEmptyLayers/

*Disclaimer: I'm the plugin's author.*

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly where you're up to it's a bit difficult, but here's the nuts and bolts:

```
layermap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
RemoveLayers = []
for name, layer in layermap.iteritems():
    if layer.isValid():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            if layer.featureCount() == 0:
                RemoveLayers.append(layer.id())
if len(RemoveLayers) > 0:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers( RemoveLayers )
```

I was also going to comment on http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RemoveEmptyLayers/ but as the author has already answered that one I'll just upvote his answer.

Also have a read of [How to remove a vector QgsVectorLayer from QGis python plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42363/how-to-remove-a-vector-qgsvectorlayer-from-qgis-python-plugin) which is related.